# Создание таблицы в Mysql с помощью Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, openserver

Я хочу добавить свою созданную сущность в базу Mysql, код срабатывает, но в mysql создается только таблица hibernate_sequence, а моей сущности нет.

application.properties:

```
    server.port=8081
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/web_blog
spring.datasource.username=mysql
spring.datasource.password=mysql
```

Точка входа:

```
    package com.homefood.blog;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BlogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlogApplication.class, args);


    }

}
```

Репозиторий:

```
    package com.homefood.blog.repository;

import com.homefood.blog.models.Recipe;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface RecipeRepository extends CrudRepository<Recipe, Long> { 
}
```

Cущность

```
package com.homefood.blog.models;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Recipe {
    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)  
private Long id;


private String title, ingredients, full_text;
private boolean like;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала создать таблицу а потом замапить класс.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вы хотите, чтобы у вас таблицы генерировались сами по вашим `@Entity` классам. Для этого пропишите в `application.properties`:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Либо, если вас `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Возможные значения этого конфигурационного параметра:

- **validate** - производит валидацию на соответствие структуры вашей БД и ваших сущностей и ругается, если что-то не совпадает.
- **update** - производит проверку на соответствие структуры вашей БД и ваших сущностей и производит апдейты в БД, если что-то не совпадает. Никогда не удаляет что-то, даже если оно уже не используется.
- **create** - сначала удаляет ту структуру, что есть, потом пересоздает заново.
- **create-drop** - то же самое, что и **create**, за исключением того, что `hibernate` удаляет структуру после выполнения всех операций. Удобно при тестировании.
- **none** - ничего не происходит.

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  был подключен

Comment: Попробуйте `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/web_blog?createDatabaseIfNotExist`